# Help with substituting T(1) in a recurrence relation where I have a T(n/2^k) instead

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have to find the closed form of recurrence relations but I got stuck on this problem:

Given:

$$T(1) = 0$$

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2$$

My answer so far:

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2$$
$$T(n/2) = 4T(n/2) + 6$$
$$T(n/4) = 8T(n/8) + 14$$
$$T(n/8) = 16T(n/16) + 30$$
$$T(k) = 2^k * T(n/2^k) + 2^(k+1) - 2$$

The next step would be to substitute $k$ for $n-1$, but my $T(n/2^k)$ would not turn into a $T(1)$ to substitute the given $T(1)=0$. What do I do next?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $T(1)=0,T(2)=2,T(4)=6,T(8)=14,\cdots $ , can you prove the pattern here is $T(n)=2n-2$.